# how can i make this code better?because it doesn't work now

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio

I have written this simple code in visual studio but it doesn't work.
please help me :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" lang="en">

</head>
<body>
    <img src="NewFolder/001.jpg" width="100" height="500" alt="" border="0" onclick="showpicture1();" />

    <script>
        function showpicture1() {
            imgMain.src = "NewFolder/001.jpg";
            imgMain.width = 400;
            imgMain.height = 300;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be useful if you add a description about what does not work and you have tried so far.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a technical description of a problem. What doesn't work? Also, the `<input> ` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Your ```imgMain``` is **not** defined.   Define using it ```let imgMain = document.getElementsByTagName(''img')[0]```;

Comment: Your imgMain is not initialized, do something like `var imgMain = document.getElementById('imageId')`. I think you are a beginner, use browser console (press f12) to find the javascript errors before posting a question to SO.

Comment: ```imgMain``` is nothing you defined anywhere. Add a parameter to the function and pass ```this``` when you are calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your script tag is in the wrong place.
You should include it or inside your  tags or after your  like:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" lang="en">
      <script>
       function showpicture1() {
        var imgMain = document.getElementById('main');
        imgMain.src = "NewFolder/001.jpg";
        imgMain.width = 400;
        imgMain.height = 300;
      }
    </script>
    </head>
   <body>
    <img id="main" src="NewFolder/001.jpg" width="100" height="500" alt="" border="0" 
    onclick="showpicture1();" />
   </body>
  </html>
```

Preferrably, I would rather put it inside the head tag for being able to do DOM manipulations and therefore validating it. I would also declare the variable as var imgMain and getting it through assigning an id to the img. I hope that helps.

Comment: It still wont work. imgMain is not initialized.

Comment: And where is ```imgMain``` defined?

Comment: Check my edited post. Sorry for not having seen it before.

Comment: thanks for your answers.my problem solved.